# $\int_{0}^{1} t^2 \sqrt{(1+4t^2)}dt$ solve

Tags: integration

$$\int_{0}^{1} t^2 \sqrt{(1+4t^2)}dt$$

**my attempt**

$$t = \frac{1}{2}\tan(u)$$

$$dt = \frac{1}{2}\sec^2(u)du\\$$

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1} t^2 \sqrt{(1+4t^2)}dt&=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\tan^2(u)}{4} \sqrt{1+\tan^2(u)}\frac{1}{2}\sec^2(u)du\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{1} \tan^2(u)\sec^{3}(u)du\\
&= \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1} (\sec^2(u) - 1)(\sec^{3}(u))du\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{1} \sec^5(u)du - \frac{1}{8} \int_{0}^{1}\sec^3(u)du
\end{align}$$

what now?

Comment: After the substitution, the limit should be from $0$ to $\arctan(2)$, not from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: use $2t = \sinh x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We substitute $$t=\frac{\tan(u)}{2}$$ then$$dt=\frac{\sec^2(u)}{2}du$$ and
$$\sqrt{4t^2+1}=\sqrt{\tan^2(u)+1}=\sec(u)$$ and our integral will be
$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{4}\tan^2(u)\sec^3(u)du$$ and this is
$$\frac{1}{8}\int\sec^3(u)(\sec^2(u)-1)du$$ and then we need the formula
$$\int\sec^m(u)du=\frac{\sin(u)\sec^{m-1}(u)}{m-1}+\frac{m-2}{m-1}\int\sec^{m-2}du$$

Answer (score 2):

To compute the integral in question first consider that $$\cosh^2(x)-\sinh^2(x)=1,$$ so $$\cosh^2(x)=1+\sinh^2(x).$$

Making the substitution $t=\frac{\sinh(x)}{2},$ then $4t^2=\sinh^2(x),$ and we get $dt=\frac{\cosh(x)}{2}dx$

$$\int t^2 \sqrt{(1+4t^2)}dt=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}\cosh(x)dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\cosh^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{32}\sinh(4x)-4x\right) +C.$$

I leave the change of parameter for $t=0$ and $t=1$ for you to finish.

Comment: how do I set the x back into t?

Comment: For $t=0,$ solve $0=\sinh(x)/2$ then $t=1,$ solve $1=\sinh(x)/2.$ You can find a formula for inverse sinh.

Answer (score 0):

Hint.  I would say

$\int \sec^5u\,du = \int\frac{\cos u\,du}{\cos^6u}=\int\frac{\cos u\,du}{(1-\sin^2u)^3}$ and after substitution

$\sin u = v,\quad \cos u \,du = dv$

it will be an integral part of the rational function.

Edit:

I will add: The given integral is the so-called binomial integral with a specific solution. See

http://www.nabla.hr/CL-IndefIntegralB5.htm

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
\int t^2 \sqrt{(1+4t^2)}dt&=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(x)}\cosh(x)dx\\
&=\frac{1}{8}\int{\sinh^2(x)}\cosh^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{8\times 32}\left(\sinh(4x)-4x\right) +C \\
&= \frac{1}{256}\left((4\sinh(x)\cosh^3(x) + 4\sinh^3(x)\cosh(x)) - 4x\right) + C\\
&=\left[\frac{1}{256}\left((4(2t)(\sqrt{1+4t^2})^3 + 4(2t)^3\sqrt{1+4t^2}) - 4\sinh^{-1}(2t)\right)\right]_{0}^{1} \approx 0.6063
\end{align}$$